# GetSystemInfo() returns different values for max application address

Tags: c#, winapi

I want to call Windows' `GetSystemInfo()` API function in C# in order to retrieve `maximumApplicationAddress` and `minimumApplicationAddress` for scanning the memory of the computer.

I wrote a simple program that outputs these value:

```
SYSTEM_INFO sys_info = new SYSTEM_INFO();
GetSystemInfo(out sys_info);
Console.WriteLine("Min Address: {0:X}", sys_info.minimumApplicationAddress.ToUInt64());
Console.WriteLine("Max Address: {0:X}", sys_info.maximumApplicationAddress.ToUInt64());
```

When I run this program, by the debugger(using the Start button), it shows this:

```
Min Address: 10000
Max Address: 7FFEFFFF
```

But when I build it, and run the executable file, it shows this:

```
Min Address: 10000
Max Address: FFFEFFFF
```

The difference between Max Addresses is a little strange to me. Can you please explain the reason?

Comment: The first one 7FFEFFFF is 2gb, the second one is 4gb. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891593/the-maximum-amount-of-memory-any-single-process-on-windows-can-address) it may be from this: "32 bit on 64 bit OS: 2 GB, unless set to large address space aware, in which case 4 GB." -- so maybe the debugger is using non-large address aware code but the build version is?

Comment: Yes, you are right. According to the linked question, running `editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO Program.exe` made the built program act like the debugger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an implementation detail that *should* not concern you.  You see FFFEFFFF because you are running on a 64-bit operating system and your EXE project's Platform target is set to AnyCPU and the "Prefer 32-bit" option is ticked.  The default settings for a .NET project.  The AnyCPU option gets the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE option bit in the executable file header set, tells the OS to provide 4 GB of address space on a 64-bit OS.  You'll always get 7FFEFFFF on a 32-bit OS.

Set the Platform target to x86 to see the difference.  Project > Properties > Build tab.

If you want the Debug build to produce the same value then you need to use Project > Properties > Debugging > untick the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" option.  The hosting process is another EXE, yourproject.vshost.exe.  That it doesn't have the option bit set is, arguably, a bug.  But most likely a convenient shortcut for a gritty problem.

You can see the difference between the two with Dumpbin.exe /headers.  Reported as "Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses".

Answer (score 0):

To examine application's address space, it is better to use `VirtualQuery` or `VirtualQueryEx` Windows API functions, than to scan the memory page by page (or 64KB region by 64KB region). The Ex variant allows you to examine address space of a process different from yours.

You original question has been answered in the commenct(s) above.

Comment: I'm passing values given by `GetSystemInfo()` to `VirtualQueryEx()` to find which pages are assigned to the process

Comment: There is no need to use these addresses at all. Just pass the NULL address to the first `VirtualQueryEx` call. You get a `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure describing the region starting with that address. The structure includes also the size of the region, so in your second call to `VirtualQueryEx`, you pass `NULL + RegionSize` as address value. And so forth. `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` also informs you about stae of the pages within the region (free, reserved, commited), their protection (read, write, execute) etc.