# Can bad C code cause a Blue Screen of Death?

Tags: c, bsod

I am a new coder in c, recently moved over from python, but still like to challenge myself with fairly ambitious projects (like a chess program), and have found that my computer suffers an unusual number of BSODs, both when I am running a program and not (admittedly, attempting to use the entirety of my memory as a hash table may not have been the greatest idea).

So my question is, are these most likely caused by my crappy c code, or is it more likely that my 3 year old, overworked laptop is the culprit?
If it could be the code, what are the big things I should avoid doing so as to prevent this?

Comment: For bsod the culprit is the OS, a driver or a hardware problem.

Comment: BSODs are caused by inadequate cooling, failing hardware, or buggy drivers. It's very unlikely your code is causing your computer to crash.

Comment: Well mostly you want to avoid BSODs (or other crashes for that matter - windows can bug out in various ways) - in the most common scenarios I mean.

But yeah spawning infinite threads in a non controlled fashion will do the trick. I've done it - either BSOD or black screen.

Comment: Those operating systems (even Darwin I've caused to reboot) are not perfect by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BSOD usually contains some information as to what caused it.

What information it contains, and how exactly it is displayed depends on the version of Windows you are running.

As can be seen from the list here:
https://hetmanrecovery.com/recovery_news/bsod-errors

Most BSOD errors come from device / driver / kernel code, and not from your typical userland program.

That said, it might be possible to trigger BSOD if your code uses particularly low level windows API, especially if you run it with administrator privileges.

Note, that simply filling up memory will result in allocations for your program failing, and possibly your program, but not the whole OS crashing.
Also, [windows does place limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891593/the-maximum-amount-of-memory-any-single-process-on-windows-can-address) on how much an individual process can allocate.

One final note:

"3 year old laptop" does not provide enough information to tell anything about your hardware, since there are different tiers of laptops available, and some of the high end 3 year old ones will still be better performing then a mid tier one bought yesterday.

As a troubleshooting measure, I would recommend backing up your data, making a clean install of your OS (aka "format the machine"), then making sure all your drivers are up to date.

You may also want to try hardware diagnostic tools, such as memtes86, check SMART on your storage, etc.

Comment: To check the SMART data/status of your hard drive or SSD, I recommend gsmartcontrol. Downloads for Windows and other OSs are available here: https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/Downloads

Answer (score 1):

It's not *supposed* to be possible for anything you do in an ordinary "user space" program to crash the whole computer. Something else must also be wrong. Here are some possibilities:

- If you are making the computer do CPU- and RAM-intensive work for long periods, you may stress the hardware to the point where a marginally defective component fails. Usually it's either the RAM, the power supply, or the cooling fans at fault.

  Make sure your power supply is rated for all of the kit you have, running simultaneously.  Make sure you have enough airflow for the amount of heat you're generating; check for dust-clogged heatsinks and fans that aren't actually spinning. If you have more than one RAM stick, take one out at a time and see if that makes the problem disappear.

  I'd *like* to tell you to get error-correcting RAM if you don't have it already, but for infuriating market differentiation reasons you'd have to replace the motherboard and CPU as well. It's still worth doing, in the long run, but it amounts to replacing the whole computer.
- You may be tickling a bug in the OS or the drivers. The most probable culprit is the GPU driver, particularly if your program does anything graphical. Regrettably, all you can do about this is make sure you're fully patched up.